# How do you delete a persistent column/field for a library with SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, library

One of my users added a column/field named Active. She was not aware that it would be flagged a persistent column/field in SharePoint.  Now when she adds huge swaths of documents to this library she has to check them all in (the field is not filled in automatically). When I attempt to delete the field it is greyed out.

I found instructions on using PowerShell, but it assumes you have an onsite server (uses `cmdlets` not available for SharePoint Online) or older versions of SharePoint (2007 , 2010 etc.).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, persistent columns are sealed meaning they cannot be deleted once created. You got 2 solutions (workaround) that you can try:

1. Hide the column instead of deleting it and remove it from the view it was 
   added.
2. Create a new document library and copy all the documents into it (*you can utilize the Open in explorer for easy copy/paste and use the quick edit to enter the metadata if a little faster fashion*)

Comment: *sigh* I was afraid that would be the solution.  Unfortunately our particular error is an unfilled field not allowing an item to be checked in, so solution 1 doesn't sound like it would work for us.  Thanks Ahmed and @gaurravs for sharing your knowledge with me.